# Background alpha transition while scrolling

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, animation, uiscrollview

In a page I am using a scroll view to show two views. For scrolling to each view I have to change the Background alpha in different manner (Or I have to show different images).

How to do  a transition effect from one image to second at the time of scrolling itself ?

I want exactly same as in twitter iPhone app profile page top scrollview transition.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to have to set some object as the UIScrollViewDelegate and then overload the function `scrollViewDidScroll:`.  Then you can get the current offset of the scrollview and set whatever variables in the UI however you wish.

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    //(Whatever you want to do here based off of scrollView.contentOffset)
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the `scrollviewDidEndScrolling` function in the same delegate, but that will not give you real time alpha blending or background changes.  It will only fire when the scrollview stops moving.

Answer (score 1):

Change the background color or the alpha of the UIView like this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat alpha = scrollView.contentOffset.x/320*0.8 ; // 0.8 is the maximum alpha allowed /
    self.myView.backgroundColor = RGBACOLOR(0, 0, 0, alpha);
    //self.myView.alpha = alpha;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the background while scrollview is scrolling then you should override below two functions:

```
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
-(void)scrollViewWillEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I am not too late with the answer :P

```
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    //update images alpha and indicator
    let xPosition = scrollView.contentOffset.x
    let width = scrollView.contentSize.width
    let pageWidth = width / 3
    
    imageViewPage1.alpha = min(1, max(0, 1 - xPosition/pageWidth))
    imageViewPage2.alpha = min(1, max(0, 1 - abs((xPosition-pageWidth)/pageWidth)))
    imageViewPage3.alpha = min(1, max(0, 1 - abs((xPosition-pageWidth*2)/pageWidth)))
}
```